# async/awaitによる非同期処理の無限ループの書き方について

Tags: c#, 非同期, マルチスレッド

Visual C#にて、現在あるWindows formアプリを作っています。
チェックボックスにチェックを入れると、その間はずっと裏で別の作業をしていて欲しいです。
その際UIはかたまらないようにしたいと思い、非同期処理で作ることにしました。
下記が自分が現在考えているコーディングなのですが、async/awaitを使った無限ループの非同期処理はこんな感じであっていますかね。
つたない文章で申し訳ありませんが、どなたかご指摘お願いします。

```
private async void 仕事1_CheckedChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ( 仕事1.Checked )                                  // Aさん：もしチェックされたら
    {
        try                                               // Aさん：Bさんこれやってみて
        {
            await Task.Run( async( ) => 仕事1( ) ) ;      // Aさん：Bさんに仕事1やってもらう。それまで他の仕事しとくね、問題起きたら報告頂戴
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )                            // Aさん：問題起きてるかチェックするよ
        {
            仕事1.Checked = false ;                       // Aさん：問題が起きたからチェック外しとくね
            AddLog( ex + "\r\n" , Color.Blue ) ;          // Aさん：起きた問題はログブックに書き込んどくよ
        }
    }
}

private async Task 仕事1( )
{
    while ( 仕事1.Checked )                               // Bさん：もしチェックされてたら、されてる間はずっと
    {
        書き込み作業( pid , addr , ofst ) ;               // Bさん：書き込み作業します
        await Task.Delay( 150 ).ConfigureAwait( false ) ; // Bさん：0.15秒次の作業遅れます。遅れてもAさんには支障ないです
    }
    書き込み作業終了( pid , addr , ofst ) ;               // Bさん：チェックが解除されたから書き込み作業終了します
}
```

早くにご回答感謝します...。
別スレッドからUI側の条件を持ってきたい、となるとこうすればよろしいのでしょうか。

```
var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource( ) ;                 // Aさん：仕事1をやめる時の条件を作っておくよ
var token = tokenSource.Token ;                                    // Aさん：その条件はこれね

private async void 仕事1_CheckedChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ( 仕事1.Checked )                                           // Aさん：もしチェックされたら
    {
        try                                                        // Aさん：Bさんこれやってみて
        {
            await Task.Run( async( ) => 仕事1( token ) , token ) ; // Aさん：Bさんに仕事1やってもらう。それまで他の仕事しとくね、問題起きたら報告頂戴
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )                                     // Aさん：問題起きてるかチェックするよ
        {
            仕事1.Checked = false ;                                // Aさん：問題が起きたからチェック外しとくね
            AddLog( ex + "\r\n" , Color.Blue ) ;                   // Aさん：起きた問題はログブックに書き込んどくよ
        }
    }
    else                                                           // Aさん：もしチェックが外れたら
    {
        tokenSource.Cancel( ) ;                                    // Aさん：仕事1はやめてもらうよ
    }
}

private async Task 仕事1( CancellationToken token )
{
    while ( true )                                                 // Bさん：Aさんから仕事中止の命令がこない間はずっと
    {
        書き込み作業( pid , addr , ofst ) ;                        // Bさん：書き込み作業します
        await Task.Delay( 150 ).ConfigureAwait( false ) ;          // Bさん：0.15秒次の作業遅れます。遅れてもAさんには支障ないです
        if ( token.IsCancellationRequested )                       // Bさん：Aさんから仕事中止の命令がきたら
        {
            書き込み作業終了( pid , addr , ofst ) ;                // Bさん：チェックが解除されたから書き込み作業終了します
            break ;                                                // Bさん：書き込み作業はやめます
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@sayuriさん指摘原因により問題があるので、チェックにはCancellationTokenを使用しましょう。この辺の記事を参照してみてください。

[非同期で複数処理を実行し、対話式で制御する](https://qiita.com/haminiku/items/cc299c1ed94d7ba3f9ec)
[方法: タスクとその子を取り消す](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-task-and-its-children)
[.NET FrameworkのCancellationTokenを利用してタスクをキャンセルすると振る舞いが2種類ある問題](http://mag.autumn.org/Content.modf?id=20161124183521)

Comment: 早くにご回答ありがとうございます。
先ほど質問のコードを更新しましたが、もしasync/awaitで別スレッドへ条件指定を送るならこの書き方でよろしいのでしょうか。

Comment: 先ずは機能確認のためならば、これで良いと思われます。

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> await Task.Run( async( ) => 仕事1( ) ) ;
> ```

は`仕事1()`を別スレッドで実行することを意味します。なお、WinFormsでは別スレッドからGUI要素（コントロール）を操作することは許されていません。そのため、`仕事1()`メソッド内の

> ```
> while ( 仕事1.Checked )
> ```

は不正なアクセスです。

Comment: 早くにご回答ありがとうございます。
先ほど質問のコードを更新しましたが、もしasync/awaitで別スレッドへ条件指定を送るならこの書き方でよろしいのでしょうか。